# How to build and deploy an app from local directory?

Tags: openshift

I just started exploring `OpenShift Online 3` and it seems really awesome.
I'm trying to setup a simple HTTP server.
Here are my steps using `CLI`:

1. oc login <...>
2. oc new-project <...>
3. oc new-app .

My current working folder consists of two files `package.json` and `server.js`.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Node.js app for OpenShift 3",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4"
  },
  "engine": {
    "node": "*",
    "npm": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
const ip = process.env.IP   || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '0.0.0.0'

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).send({ message: 'OK' })
})

// error handling
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something bad happened!')
})

app.listen(port, ip)
console.log('Server running on http://%s:%s', ip, port)

module.exports = app
```

---

**Here's console output:**

```
--> Creating resources ...
    imagestream "olmeo-openshift" created
    buildconfig "olmeo-openshift" created
    deploymentconfig "olmeo-openshift" created
    service "olmeo-openshift" created
--> Success
    Build scheduled, use 'oc logs -f bc/olmeo-openshift' to track its progress.
    Run 'oc status' to view your app.
```

**After build is done web console shows an error:**

```
Environment: 
    DEV_MODE=false
    NODE_ENV=production
    DEBUG_PORT=5858
Launching via npm...
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.9
npm info using node@v6.11.3
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-693.12.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs6/root/usr/bin/node" "/opt/rh/rh-nodejs6/root/usr/bin/npm" "run" "-d" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! path /opt/app-root/src/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/app-root/src/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/app-root/src/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/app-root/src/npm-debug.log
```

Apparently, `package.json` can't be found. What am I missing?

Comment: When you run ``oc new-app .`` if that is a git repo workaraa, it will deploy from the hosted git repo you push you changes to. Did you add/commit/push your changes to whatever git hosting service you are using yet? If you want to push changes from your local directory, you have to setup the build differently.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, I think that's it. The source code is stored only locally. I didn't create a remote repo for it. Is it nesessary to push it to remote repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use:

```
oc new-app .
```

in a git workarea cloned off a remotely hosted Git repository, the build will be set up to pull files from the hosted Git repository. This means that if you make local changes and don't add/commit/push them to the hosted Git repository, then they will never be used.

If you want to work from a local directory and not use a hosted Git repository, you need to use a binary input build. To do that first run:

```
oc new-build --binary --image-stream nodejs --name olmeo-openshift
```

Then start a build by running:

```
oc start-build olmeo-openshift --from-dir=.
```

This will upload files from the local directory.

Once the first image has been built, then you can run:

```
oc new-app olmeo-openshift
```

to deploy the image, and:

```
oc expose svc/olmeo-openshift
```

to give it a public URL.

Each time you make code changes, run again:

```
oc start-build olmeo-openshift --from-dir=.
```

Comment: one quick question. Where do you know these commands from? I've looked through the official docs and couldn't find anything like that. Check out `new-build` [command](https://docs.openshift.com/online/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#new-build), for example, there's nothing there.

Comment: found it [here](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html)

Comment: I can't quite get it to work. My builds are failing. Here's the error from webconsole logs `error streaming logs from build pod: olmeo/olmeo-2-build container: , container "sti-build" in pod "olmeo-2-build" is not available`. What am I missing?

Comment: and also this error `Evicted: The node was low on resource: [DiskPressure].`

Comment: Create a separate question don't add questions as comments on existing questions. But if you are on OpenShift Online Starter us-west-1, they are going through an upgrade of it at present and it is having some issues during the process of that which might be causing this.